# How to check Nginx is work? (Python: Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

The project path is "/home/API_AIcustomerservice"

The API url is "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5061"

The python file of API named "start_honsecaistk.py"

I'm very sure Gunicorn and Flask is worked. (I can access the API url successfully)

I run Gunicorn by command "`gunicorn -c /home/API_AIcustomerservice/gconfig.py start_honsecaistk:app`" with gconfig.py

[gconfig.py]

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import multiprocessing
debug = True
loglevel = 'debug'
bind = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5061'
pidfile = 'log/gunicorn.pid'
logfile = 'log/debug.log'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

About Nginx
I edited the file: `vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /home/API_AIcustomerservice;
        server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5061/;
        }
        location ~ ^\/static\/.*$ {
            root /home/API_AIcustomerservice;
        }
}
```

After edited, I run `sudo service nginx restart`

And then.
How do I check Nginx is work with the API url?
I ask this question because I run `sudo service nginx stop`
and the API url still can be access.
I can't see the Nginx's affect.

Thank you for taking the time.
I thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're binding with gunicorn not on localhost you want to be proxied out with nginx but on external ip you have. So you could change either that or proxy pass url.

When you'll stop nginx it won't kill your application and you will still able to access it if it's running. To check whether if nginx proxy is working fine you can curl the url, e.g. in your case it's `curl http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally found the problem was that I had another application use the 80 port (xampp apache). After I close the apache, your suggest works.